# Random Sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, conditional-expectation, density-function

Struggling with one last question.

A random sequence X0, X1, X2, X3..... is generated from X0 by the rule

```
Xk+1 =


Xk with probability 1/2
2Xk with probability p where 0 < p =< 1/2`
Xk/2 with probability q = 1/2 - p
```

a. For any allowed value of p, find the probabilities of all possible values of X2 if X0 = 4

b. Find the value p that makes X a martingale

I'm guessing we set up a discrete  expected value with probability weights 0.5, p and q but I'm not quite sure.

Any help would be appreciated, it's a relatively new type of question

Answer (score 2):

In this particular setting $X_k$ is a martingale iff
$E(X_{k+1} | X_k) = X_k \iff  E(X_{k+1} | X_k)(p) = X_k   \iff \frac 12 X_k + 2pX_k + \frac 1 2(\frac 1 2 - p) X_k  = X_k $

You can then divide by $X_k$ and  solve for $p$

$\frac 12  + 2p + \frac 1 4-\frac 1 2  p   = 1 \iff \frac 3 2 p = \frac 14  \iff  p = \frac 16$

$q =  \frac 1 3$

It makes sense that $q$ is lower than $p$ because expectation is in value. When you double $X_0=4$ it applies a deviation in value of $4$ $(X_1=8 = X_0+4)$ to the expectation. Dividing by 2 only applies a deviation of $-2$ $(X_1=2 = X_0-2)$. Therefore you need to divide by 2 twice as frequently as you multiply by two in order to keep the expectation constant.

Comment: Thats perfect thank you very much I'll try that

Comment: Hi I've tried this, would I be correct in thinking that P is 0.333 leaving q to be 0.167

Comment: Hi so I have computed what I believe to be the correct probabilities in part A which is p = 0.333 q = 0.167

Part B would be a martingale if P was equal to 0.167

I have one final part 
C. A game is played for this value of p.

Initial stake at X0= 100 and stops when they have more than 1000e and less than 10e.

Find probability they leave with more than 1000e

Assuming my value for P is correct, the expected value of 100e at X1 is 124.95 but again I'm not sure from here

Comment: I added the solution for $p$ as well as an alternative intuitive way to find it. You should add this second question (complete version) to your original post (Add the mention 'Edit:')

Comment: Hi thanks I will do that I believe I figured it out. 1000w + (10-w) = 100 so 9%

Answer (score 0):

For a, there are three possible transitions at each step.  That means there are nine possible two step transitions.  Compute $X_2$ and the probability for each of those and make a list.  Some of the $X_2$ values will be the same.

For b, have you looked up the definition of a martingale?  Given $X_n$ what is the expected value of $X_{n+1}?$  These are supposed to be equal.  You need to find the $p$ that makes them so.

Comment: Yeah I can write out Martingale etc I wasn't sure how to apply to this question. It's just more odd when I see it as a word problem